# Merge a picture color in other picture using Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to merge the color of one picture in other picture. As the picture below is showing. I paste a picture on circle. But there is a clear distinction between the two pictures. I want to get rid of it. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:
1: You could make a Clipping Mask, use the pen tool and trace the object, once you have drawn a line around what you what removed from the background select your outline and your image. goto top menu item Object > Clipping Mask > Make. This will clip your image and hide the background.

2: The image your are using my be tough for step one. Try re-exporting the image as a PNG or GIF with a transparent background then open it in illustrator. You will need to either "open" from within ai or "open with" ai. Copy/paste will not keep the transparency depending on the tools you are using.

My guess is step two will be your easiest solution because of the shadow elements. Good luck!

-Added Edit-
3: Open the original image file and change the background hex value to match the final desired background. This solution is less valuable because you won't have the ability to edit or change your mind about the color while your working.